# How to filter the automatic events from Firebase Analytics when creating a funnel?

Tags: firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase Analytics and triggering custom events. I created a funnel, but Firebase is showing the automatic events (such as screen_view, like in the screenshot).

[image]

I don't want to view those events, I want to view only the events I created. How do I do that? I tried setting filters such as  “Event name does not exactly contain screen_view” and the opposite, but the result is confusing: all events are filtered out or screen_view keeps showing.
I'd be really grateful if someone could help me understand how to filter out these events and only keep the custom ones, thanks.

[image]